# Espresso: AppNotIdleException

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am continuously getting this error when I land on a page. What could be the solution to this?

```
android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 4539 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
```

Comment: Do you use the IdlingResources? Perhaps you miss somewhere a "decrement" to report idle?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56198539/4797289

Answer (score 8):

It might occur due to any UI element which is creating itself infinitely. For example, you have a Custom ProgressBar or Snackbar which is set to invisible/gone in xml and you are setting it visible in java code. But it might re-paint itself in invisible/gone state also due to ill-written code. So, go through any Custom UI elements as well if you have any.

Comment: This was the problem for me (invalidate() accidentally getting called on loop).  To help diagnose this problem, you can enable Developer Options > Show Surface Updates.  Offending views will flash very rapidly.

Comment: Yes...this is the way to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely because you didn't turn off the following 3 settings in you developer options:

- Window animation scale
- Transition animation scale
- Animator duration scale

For more informations read the [tips](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html) to set up Espresso.

If that is not the case something seems to be interacting with your screen while the test is running.